# magical record delete one to many relationship all children

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a one to many relationship like teacher with students. Now I want to delete all students of a given teacher. I use the code like this:

```
[Student MR_deleteAllMatchingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"teacher == %@" argumentArray:@[teacher]]];
```

... but deletes the given teacher. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the delete rule from "cascade" to "no action".

Comment: Why cant you simply iterate through all the students of a teacher and delete them?